# Calculate sum of overlapping timestamp differences and duplicate time

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a dataframe with two columns containing start and end timestamp of a session:

```
1 2017-12-04 05:26:15   2017-12-04 05:28:39
2 2017-12-04 05:26:31   2017-12-04 05:34:36
3 2017-12-04 05:28:44   2017-12-04 05:28:54
4 2017-12-04 05:29:05   2017-12-04 05:30:57
5 2017-12-04 05:31:04   2017-12-04 05:31:13
6 2017-12-04 05:31:06   2017-12-04 05:31:13
7 2017-12-04 05:31:26   2017-12-04 05:43:18
8 2017-12-04 05:33:31   2017-12-04 05:35:54
9 2017-12-04 05:34:12   2017-12-04 05:35:24
```

I need to calculate the sum of the differences (i.e. durations) of these sessions excluding duplicate time and duplicate time 
For example: consider sessions 7,8,9. Start at 05:31:26 (session 7) and end at 05:43:18 (session 7). But in between there are multiple sessions open.

The result for 7,8,9 would be:
Duration excluding duplicate time: 11 minutes 52 seconds
Duplicate time: 2 minutes 23 seconds (session 8) + 1 minute 12 seconds (session 9) = 3 minutes 35 seconds

How to achieve this in python?

Comment: So your effort? Can we see it

Comment: Its bit broad and hard to understand, to make answer understand the problem easy its better you provide the expected output in the form of data given.

Comment: does this even have a unique solution?  this seems like an underspecified problem and is pretty hard to understand...  if two interval overlap, how do you determine which interval is the duplicate and which is the original?  seems like you may want to explore converting to a pandas interval object, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Hi sorry for the bad explanation. Figured out the solution in the meanwhile - not sure if it's the most efficient one, but it works.

```
for i in range(0,len(inter_data)):
### PLEASE INDENT HERE WHEN USING THE CODE ###

if i == 0:
    begin_first = inter_data.iloc[i]['begin_timestamp']
    end_first = inter_data.iloc[i]['end_timestamp']
    dupl = 0
    dur = (end_first-begin_first).seconds
else:
    begin = inter_data.iloc[i]['begin_timestamp']    
    end = inter_data.iloc[i]['end_timestamp']

    if begin >= end_first:
        dur = dur + (end-begin).seconds
        end_first = end
    elif (begin < end_first) and (end >= end_first) :
        dur = dur + (end-end_first).seconds
        dupl = dupl + (end_first-begin).seconds
        end_first = end
    elif (begin <= end_first) and (end < end_first):
        dupl = dupl + (end-begin).seconds
```